# Is Selenium TestRunner actively maintained?

Tags: selenium

I am new to the Selenium world. I am curious to know whether Selenium Test Runner is actively maintained or not? Also can you point me to the download package of Selenium Test Runner. I am not able to find in the Selenium Home Page (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: What's Selenium Test Runner? I assume you mean the IDE?

Comment: @Arran: Here's link of the test runner GUI: http://philip.html5.org/demos/xforms/0.6.2/_testsuite/selenium/core/TestRunner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [Selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp).

> TestRunner Mode: Allows you to run the test case in a browser loaded
>   with the Selenium-Core TestRunner. The TestRunner is not commonly used
>   now and is likely to be deprecated.

So yes, TestRunner seems to be no longer maintained (or it won't be in the near future).

Comment: I have pasted a link in the comments below my question. Can you have a look and reconfirm this?

Comment: I've never used TestRunner so I can't really confirm it but I thing documentation says very clearly that this is going to be deprecated project.